# Jquery when slide down, changing background color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some HTML, CSS and JQuery Code. When I do slide down and up, I want to change my "h3" background color with jquery like the below image, it should be reddish. As a result, when I slide down, it must be changed with jquery code.

[image: Sidebar]

My accordion sidebar code is :

```
`<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></span>Notifications<span class="notification-span">29</span></h3>
    </li>
    <li >
      <h3 class="tooltip"><span class="icon-coffee"><i class="fab fa-slideshare"></i></span>Summary </h3>
    <ul class">
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>

    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>Publish</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      
    </ul>
    </li>

 <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></span>Engage</h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3><span class="icon-cloud"><i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i></span>Listen</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <h3><span class="icon-cloud"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></span>Report</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li"><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
        
      </ul>
      </li>


  </ul>
</div>`
```

My Accordion Css code is:

```
/*Accordion Menu*/

#accordion {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #393d42;
    color:#fff;
}

#accordion h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:34px;
    padding:10px 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  #accordion h3:hover{
      background-color: #f55661;
  }

  #accordion h3:link{
    background-color:red;

  }
 

  /* links */
  #accordion ul ul li a{
    color:white;
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:27px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .1s;
    background-color: #32363a;
    
  }
  
  /* hover effect */
  #accordion ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #f55661;
  }


  /* hide non-actives by default */
  #accordion ul ul{
    display:none;
  }
  
  #accordion li.active ul{
    display:block;
  }

  
  /* Icon font styles */
  #accordion h3 span{
    font-size:16px;
    padding-right:10px;
  }

  i{
      font-weight: 100;
     color:#f55661;
  }

  h3:hover i{
      color: #fff;
  }
```

I have to change my jquery code. Here we are :

```
    $("#accordion h3").click(function(){

  // slide up the list
  $("#accordion ul ul").slideUp("fast");
  //$( "#accordion ul  li h3 ").css('background-color', '#f55661  ');


  // slide down if it is closed
  if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")){
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast")
  }
})
```

Edit:I added this code but it makes all h3 reddish. I have to choose specific one, like "this" command.

```
   $("#accordion ul li h3").css('background-color', '#f55661  ');
```

Comment: Toggling a class is a cleaner way than using `css()`. Then write style rules based on that class

Comment: I tried toggling a class but It couldn't find it easier, it comes me more complicated.

Comment: Not when you need to look for another open one and undo it. Toggling classes is almost always the easiest approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle a class that applies the background color using the [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function.

Additionally, you have to loop through all other lists and remove the `open` class. This can be done via `siblings().find('h3').removeClass('open')`, which loops through all siblings, finds the `h3` element and removes the `open` class.

```js
$("#accordion h3").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('h3').removeClass('open');
  $("#accordion ul ul").slideUp("fast");
  if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
  }
})
```

```css
/*Accordion Menu*/

#accordion {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #393d42;
  color: #fff;
}

#accordion h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#accordion h3:hover {
  background-color: #f55661;
}

#accordion h3:link {
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip.open {
  background-color: #f55661;
}


/* links */

#accordion ul ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .1s;
  background-color: #32363a;
}


/* hover effect */

#accordion ul ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f55661;
}


/* hide non-actives by default */

#accordion ul ul {
  display: none;
}

#accordion li.active ul {
  display: block;
}


/* Icon font styles */

#accordion h3 span {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

i {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #f55661;
}

h3:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.open {
  background-color: #f55661;
}
.open i{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <h3><span class="icon-dashboard"><i class="far fa-bell"></i></span>Notifications<span class="notification-span">29</span></h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="tooltip"><span class="icon-coffee"><i class="fab fa-slideshare"></i></span>Summary </h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud "><i class="fas fa-edit "></i></span>Publish</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Ipsum</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud "><i class="far fa-comments "></i></span>Engage</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud "><i class="fas fa-volume-up "></i></span>Listen</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Ipsum</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3><span class="icon-cloud "><i class="fas fa-chart-line "></i></span>Report</h3>
      <ul>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Lorem</a></li>
        <li class="accordion-li "><a href="# ">Ipsum</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works thank you so much. Basically why you can't suggest slide up and down ? Are they out of date ?

Comment: @Burakkepuc No problem. What do you mean by suggest?

Comment: But now I have trouble with icon colors. It stucks, doesn't change.

Comment: @Burakkepuc Which icon colors are you talking about?

Comment: It is font-awesome icons that I can define into the h3 tag.  It's all icon color stucks white when I toggle them.

Comment: @Burakkepuc I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Spectric's answer, toggling classes is probably ideal, especially if you want to apply CSS transitions to make the color change smoother.

However, given the trajectory you were on, you can accomplish what you're trying to do with the following jQuery:

```js
$("#accordion h3").click(function(){

  // Close all previously-opened menu items
  $("#accordion ul ul").slideUp("fast");
  // Reset color of all h3s to dark gray
  $('#accordion h3').css('background-color', '#393d42')

  // then...
  // For the clicked header, set red bg color
    $(this).css('background-color', '#f55661');
    // and slide it's sub menu open
    $(this).next().slideDown("fast")
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My sidebar is bouncing when I try to click it.